# How to write a script that creates hotkeys?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a lot of little hot keys defined, such as:

```
; Open CMD
#c::
    Run, cmd.exe
    WinWait, ahk_exe cmd.exe
    WinActivate
Return
```

I'd like to build a function that takes the exe and hot key, and it will bind the app with that hot key. Here's what I have so far:

```
bind_exe_to_hotkey(exe,hotkey)
{
    run_label:
        Run, %exe%
        WinWait, ahk %exe%
        WinActivate
    Return

    HotKey, %hotkey%, run_label
}

bind_exe_to_hotkey("cmd.exe","#c")
```

However, this just opens a command window. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier/better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your function just opens a command window because it returns before "HotKey" is executed.  The "run_label" does nothing; it's just a *goto*-like entry pointer.  The Run, WinWait and WinActivate statements are executed and then the function returns before the HotKey statement is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binds key to a function that handles launching an executable:

```
#c: launch("cmd.exe")
#n: launch("notepad.exe")

launch(exe)
{
   Run, %exe%
   WinWait, ahk %exe%
   WinActivate
}
```